# Determine the best placement for attic ladder installation

Tags: drywall, attic, ladder

I have recently purchased an attic ladder from HD to install myself in my townhouse.  I have determined 2 good installation points that will not interfere with future furniture placement. The options are

1. Install the ladder in the hall, with the stairs facing the master Bedroom.
2. Install the ladder in the master bedroom, going away from the hallway.
3. Install the ladder in the master bedroom, opening into the hall.

Note, the unit says it needs 6'2" swing clearance, which means it must go into the bedroom door slightly, otherwise I cannot trim the unit.

Which open is best, does it matter?

Comment: A diagram would really help here.

Comment: yeah I was hacking one together but it was NOT to scale

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stairs should gain access to the attic in such a way that:

1) one has max. headroom,

2) the attic stairwell doesn't prevent access to any part of the attic,

3) the stairs permits a path of travel to a ground floor exterior door (ie. doesn't come down into the hallway in such a way one would have to close the stairs to exit the bldg.)

4) the stairs would not likely require furniture to be moved to be used.

Comment: +1 for number 3, as I read the options in the question I was trying to figure out the words to explain that thought.